# dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined

Tags: javascript, webforms, dojo, dijit.layout, dijit.dialog

I am using dojo with .NET webforms for creating popup menu and I am getting below error when I try to load the page.
"dojo/parser::parse() error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute' of undefined"

it would be very useful if someone can share a blog on how to use dojo with webforms.
Below is my code for reference. please check and help me resolve this issue.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="xyz.aspx.cs" Inherits="xyz" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title></title>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Scripts/dojo/resources/dojo.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/dojo/dojo.js" ></script>

</head>
<body class="claro" style="height:100px;width:100px;">

 <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="height:100%; width:100%">

        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBar">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuBarItem">
                    <span>File</span>
                    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu">
                        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem">Open</div>
                        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem">Save</div>
                        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuItem">
                            <span> Recent...</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">

     document.getElementById("pnlControlList").remove();
     $("#navbar").remove();

     require(["dojo/parser"], function (parser) {
         parser.parse();
     });

 </script>
</body>
</html>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code causes problem:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuItem">
   <span> Recent...</span>
</div>
```

`dijit/PopupMenuItem` needs to contain dropdown element as its child.

```js
require(["dojo/parser", 
  "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/MenuBar", 
  "dijit/PopupMenuBarItem", "dijit/DropDownMenu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dijit/PopupMenuItem"
], function (parser) {
         parser.parse();
     });
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />

<body class="claro">
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" style="height:100px; width:100px">

        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"
            data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuBar">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuBarItem">
                    <span>File</span>
                    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu">
                        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem">Open</div>
                        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem">Save</div>
                        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/PopupMenuItem">
                            <span> Recent...</span>
                            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/DropDownMenu">
                              <div data-dojo-type="dijit/MenuItem">Some Item</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Note: I've also added all dijit modules contained in html to required modules. I don't know whether it's mandatory in .NET but some environments throw error without it (ex. jsfiddle)